# Prepared statement not inserting to database with image file

Tags: php, html, mysql, image

I am attempting to send an insert query to my db with data and an img file. This is my first attempt at sending an img file and a prepared statement. I have been stuck on this for about a month any no matter what I do it will not send. As of now nothing is inserting to my db.

I am just trying to send basic information to my database and send an img file to a folder I have called productpics and then move the name of the file over to my db.

I even just tried to add a else statement for the query part of the prepared statement and I can't get the echo part to display after submitting my form. I have validation before this for certain parts of the data (nothing to do with the img upload yet). I tested this and the validation is working and not stopping the query. I think the issue resides somewhere in my prepared statement or the form.

I'm not sure if the extra button I have for the img upload field is stopping this? But I had it like this before when I had a simple insert query and everything send except for the img file to my db. Now nothing is sending.

Does anyone see anything that I'm doing wrong that is stopping this from working?

```
if($validation->passed()) {
        if(isset($_POST['create'])){ 
            $product_id = trim( $_POST['product_id'] );
            $name = trim( $_POST['name'] );
            $price = trim( $_POST['price'] );
            $saleprice = trim( $_POST['saleprice'] );
            $final_price = trim( $_POST['final_price'] );
            $shippingprice = trim( $_POST['shippingprice'] );
            $category = trim( $_POST['category'] );
            $item_details = trim( $_POST['item_details'] );
            $item_details2 = trim( $_POST['item_details2'] );
            $description = trim( $_POST['description'] );
            $viewproduct_type = trim( $_POST['viewproduct_type'] );
            $file = "productpics/". $_FILES['file']['name']; // save the filename

        }else {
            foreach($validation->errors() as $error) {
                echo $error, '<br>';
            }
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $file); // move the file

        //Connection
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bfb");
        /* check connection */
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
                exit();
            }



        /* create a prepared statement */
        if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO products (product_id, name, price, saleprice, final_price, shippingprice, category, item_details, item_details2, description, viewproduct_type, date, img) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW(), ?)")) {


            /* bind parameters for markers */
            $stmt->bind_param('isiiiissssss', $product_id, $name, $price, $saleprice, $final_price, $shippingprice, $category, $item_details, $item_details2, $description, $viewproduct_type, $file);

            /* execute query */
                            $stmt->execute();
            //if(!$stmt->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$con->error, E_USER_WARNING);}


        /* close statement */
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

                  echo "Success!";
        } else {
                   echo "Failed!";
                    }
                   }
    }
 }
 }   
 ?>
```

The form. I'm not sure if my img file upload part is messing this up? I don't know how to do this differently.

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="field">
            <label for="product_id">Product ID</label>
            <input type="text" name="product_id" class="smallinputbar" required>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="name">Product Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="inputbar" name="name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="price">Product Price</label>
            <input type="text" class="smallinputbar" name="price" required>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="saleprice">Sale Price</label>
            <input type="text" class="smallinputbar" name="saleprice">
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="final_price">Final Price</label>
            <input type="text" class="smallinputbar" name="final_price" required>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="shippingprice">Shipping Price</label>
            <input type="text" class="smallinputbar" name="shippingprice" required>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="category">Category</label>
            <input type="text" class="inputbar" name="category" required>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="item_details">Item Details</label>
            <input type="message" class="messageinput" name="item_details" required>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="item_details2">Item Details 2</label>
            <input type="message" class="messageinput" name="item_details2">
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="description">Description</label>
            <input type="message" class="messageinput" name="description" required>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="viewproduct_type">View Product Type</label>
            <select class="optionbar" name="viewproduct_type">
                <option value="Not Selected">Not Selected</option>
                <option value="a href='./viewProduct.php?view_product=$id">Standard</option>
                <option value="Option">Option</option>
            </select>
        </div>

            <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
            <label for="button">
                <input type="submit" id="button" name="create" value="Create New Product">
            </label>

    <span class="floatright">
                <input type="file" name="file" class="inputbarfile">
                <input type="submit" name="create" id="signinButton" value="Upload">
    </span>
</form>
```

Comment: You never check if the upload was successful, or if there even WAS an upload. There's a `['error']` parameter in $_FILES for a reason...

Comment: You're basically naming your file `productpics/file.jpg` with `$file = "productpics/". $_FILES['file']['name'];`

Comment: So do you guys think the query is breaking with the $file variable?

Comment: assign a variable to a destination folder, assign a variable to the filename, then append to a 3rd variable to be sent to db as the path to, and filename together. Consult the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. Also change `$stmt->execute();` to `if(!$stmt->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$con->error, E_USER_WARNING);}` to trap possible SQL errors.

Comment: I have the php error reporting on the page right now. I have also added the trigger error before and it did not show any errors.

Comment: I also noticed you have 2x inputs bearing the same name attribute `name="create"` there could be a conflict here. If you're trying to upload and query in 2 different parts, then that's another conflict.

Comment: So should I just take out the name create in the img upload? Name it something else?

Comment: Taking out<input type="submit" name="create" id="signinButton" value="Upload"> from the img file section in the form did not help the situation.